Problem with NUMLOCK on Ubuntu-Mate boot
I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu (22.04 LTS) and Ubuntu-Mate (24.04 LTS). My numlock setting in BIOS is ON. When booting, the numlock initially comes on, but when selecting Mate from GRUB, it goes off until after the login password is entered (numlockx is installed and ON). This behavior does not occur in Ubuntu so something is different between them.
Is that difference controlled in a kernel module and is there a config file or persistent command where I can change it?
